# Sorting across multiple pagination pages with will_paginate

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml, will-paginate

I am currently using will_paginate to paginate a table,sorting is also in place using jquery. The problem is that will paginate only passes the table as the current viewable table of objects say 25 of the 100 table items. So the sorting only occurs on the one page of 25. Is there a way to sort all 100 items and then paginate?

`@people = @results.records.where(active: true).order('signup_at DESC NULLS LAST').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)`

```
- if @people.any?
 %table.ui.sortable.striped.table
%thead
  %tr
    %th Name
    %th Email
    %th Phone
    %th Submissions
    %th Signed up
    %th Signup form
    %th Most recent note

%tbody
  = render @people
```

= paginate @people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be adding query parameters to your endpoint admitting different sort keys:

```
/users/2/comments?sort_key=name
/users/2/comments?sort_key=age
```

Then set this in your controller:

```
@people = @results.records.where(active: true).order("#{params['sort+key']} DESC NULLS LAST").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
```

Then you have the entire set of 100 comments sorted by the key.

What you want to achieve, 2 sorting strategies is really confusing in terms of implementation and UX. either fetch all and implement a pagination in JavaScript or leave the pagination server side. Both strategies are completely different, in one you fetch all results (JavaScript) whereas in the other you are paginating, meaning each page reload requires a query to be run, hitting the database.

Notice that you could still apply different sorts using JQuery in the current set (in this case, the 25 results you get back).

Comment: Thank you. This pointed me in the right direction. I just want to add that I found a great rails cast on implementing this http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

Comment: Ryan Bates has dome pretty nice stuff, check GoRails if you have the time, it has a subscription model around but the contntent is great.